# Wordpress Custom Page Type Author not showing

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, author

So I made a "Custom Post Type" for Wordpress and also made a single-*.php (single-yourcustomtype.php) for content-display.

Code from single-*.php:

```
<?php $author = get_the_author(); echo $author; ?>
```

It works in the content.php, but not in the single-*.php...

Any idea why is it not working or how can I display out author's name?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding 
    global $post;

Comment: Seems it solved the problem:

<?php if( have_posts() ) the_post(); ?>

Thanks for answering!